# GSON and Generic types

Tags: java, spring, gson

I've come across a problem of using Gson library and generic types(my types and collections). However they have an answer how to solve this problem, I don't think it's appropriate to write a specific message converter for the every type I've already implemented and I'll implement.

What I did is:

Implemented my own message converter:

```
public class SuperHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {

private final Charset charset;
private final Gson gson;

public CostomHttpMC_1(MediaType mediaType, String charset) {
    super(mediaType);
    this.charset = Charset.forName(charset);
    gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
}

@Override
protected Object readInternal(Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
    String jsonString = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(new InputStreamReader(inputMessage.getBody(), charset));
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, clazz);
}

@Override
protected Long getContentLength(Object obj, MediaType contentType) {
    try {
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);
        return (long) jsonString.getBytes(charset.name()).length;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        throw new InternalError(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void writeInternal(Object obj, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException {
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);
    FileCopyUtils.copy(jsonString, new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody(), charset));
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
}
```

}

It works well until I try to send a collection like `List<String>` or `some Type<T>`.

Gson has the solutions here: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Also I tried the json-lib library yesterday. What I don't like about it is in-depth scanning of all objects which I have in the hierarchy. I tried to change the cycle detection strategy from `CycleDetectionStrategy.STRICT` to `CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT`, it didn't help at all!

```
    @Override
protected void writeInternal(Object obj, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException {
    JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();  
    jsonConfig.setCycleDetectionStrategy(CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT);
    String jsonString = JSONObject.fromObject( obj ).toString();
    FileCopyUtils.copy(jsonString, new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody(), charset));
}
```

Finally, a work-around for the generic collection's problem was found out: changing from `ArrayList` to simple array helps to do serialization and deserialization. To be more specific you have to do it in a web-service, which you use in an application.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/country/info/{code}")
public void info(@PathVariable("code") String code, Model model) {

//list
    StuffImpl[] stuffList= new StuffImpl[0]; <-- this is the array I used!
stuffList= restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8084/yourApp/restService/stuff", stuffList.getClass());
model.addAttribute("stuffList", stuffList);
}
```

So this approach is working good.

I failed to found out what a solution for generic type is. I really do hate an idea to write a new converter every time I implement a new generic type.

If you know any possible solution I'd appreciate your help a lot!

I'd be on the cloud nine if anyone could help me :)

L.

Comment: Take a look at http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/. I know you might not be able to change from Gson but it does offer a very good alternative that seems better in some areas

Comment: I'm at the beggining of the project so I'd be able to swith if it really solves all problems I've already solved with gson. Now I have only one.

Comment: my advice is to make a test project and tryout both libraries side by side and see which one is easier/better. Also try and decouple your code from the actual java->json implementation so that later you can easily change it.

Comment: What I don't really like about flexjson that I have to include and exclude desired field myself. I want to have only one MessageConverter which would be able to do all work by itself. Gson aproach is better when you mark with the annotation @Expose all fields in an entity you want to be insluded.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Liviu T.! I do think it's a good advice :) but I decided to ask my colleagues who had already come across some pitfalls which json libraries have because as usually I don't have enough time for an investigation :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods where you can pass `java.lang.reflect.Type`. These methods are useful if the specified object is a generic type, e.g.:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Foo");
names.add("Bar");

// marshal
String jsonLiteral = gson.toJson(names);
System.out.println(jsonLiteral);

// unmarshal
List<String> names2;
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
}.getType();
names2 = gson.fromJson(jsonLiteral, type);
System.out.println(names2.get(0));
System.out.println(names2.get(1));
```

This will output:

```
["Foo","Bar"]
Foo
Bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sean! As I mentioned before I don't like to be stick to the actual type like ypu mentioned Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>> because it means that every time I implement new generic type I have to implement new code for it. What I want is one implementation for all types is it possible. Anyway, thank you a lot! L.